# Scrapy: upgrade the pipeline to send items

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have a class in pipelines.py that sends and threads to my server's API:

```
class MyPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        data = {
            "source_id": 'name_of_the_running_spider,
            "token": "token",
            "products": [dict(item)],
        }
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        url = 'http://for.example.com/my-api/'
        requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
        return item
```

The problem is that the pipeline sends each time under one item (`"products": [dict(item)]`). Is it possible to somehow pass a list items to **"products"** (for example `[dict(item)*10]`)? If in the spider itself, it can be organized using a loop and a counter, but how to implement it through pipeline.py

Comment: for the name of the spider just include it as a field when you yield the items from the parsing method

Comment: @Alexander yes, thank you, it works that way, just if there are alternative methods, I would like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing I have come up with a possible solution, that adds functionality to the pipeline by storing each item in a list, and having a separate method that manages the number of items collected and automatically triggers the request once length of the list has reached a certain threshold, and then resets the list back to empty.  Then in the pipelines `close_spider` method you can check if there are any remaining requests that haven't been sent and send those.

For the spider name, the pipelines `process_item` method receives the instance of the spider.  So in order to get the spider's `name` attribute all you need to do is use `spider.name`.  If instead you are trying to get the name of the spider class then you can either do some regex on `type(spider)` or simply add the class name as an attribute to the spider and get it through `spider.classname`.

For example:

**`pipelines.py`**

```py
class MyPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self._request_data = []
        self._url = 'http://for.example.com/my-api/'
        self._headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        self._max_number_of_requests = 10

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        spidername = spider.name
        if len(self._request_data) >= self._max_number_of_requests:
            self.send_post_request(spidername)
        self._request_data.append(item)
        return item

    def send_post_request(self, spidername):
        data = {"source_id": spidername,
                "token": "token",
                "products": self._request_data}
        response = requests.post(url=self._url,
                                 headers=self._headers,
                                 data=json.dumps(data))
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"REQUEST FAILED: status code {response.status_code}")
        self._request_data = []

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        if len(self._request_data) > 0:
            self.send_post_request(spider.name)
```

Comment: cool!!! I additionally output the buffer size to the settings file